# What is Path Variable in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, path-variables, omnisharp

I am coding .net core in VS Code on my Windows 10 Laptop. I am using Omnisharp C# extension but it's not working. I am getting this error if I press `view -> Output` and `Select Omnisharp Log`

```
[ERROR] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

According to this [github post regarding the above problem generated while starting Omnisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/32),
they are saying to add some path `"C:\Windows\System32".....`

So where Should I add it?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Now I am getting this error   Error occured in loading omnisharp from omnisharp.path
Could not start the server due to Error: Invalid OmniSharp version - null

Comment: Ok Thanks for ur answer